# VBA - Add, Position and Resize a picture as chart background

Tags: image, vba, excel, charts

I need to Add, Position and Resize a picture on the background of a chart that already exists.

```
Sub Add_Picture()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Input_Data As Worksheet
Set Input_Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input Data")

'###    Find Chart
Dim chrt As ChartObject
Set chrt = Input_Data.ChartObjects(Input_Data.ChartObjects.Count) ' finding the only chart on the sheet

'###    Add the picture
chrt.Chart.ChartArea.Format.Fill.UserPicture ("C:\Users\z188018\Desktop\Untitled.png") ' adding the picture
chrt.Chart.SetElement (msoElementPlotAreaNone) 'to show the picture (otherwise hidden behing a white background)

'###    Center the picture


'###    Resize the picture


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have already tried multiple times, but nothing worth mentioning, that's why I left the sections empty. I can do it manually, after running this piece of code and then:

1. Right Click on Picture
2. "Format Chart Area"
3. "Fill"
4. "Picture or Texture Fill"
5. Play around with the "Stretch Options"

Nevertheless, Recording a Macro gives me only this:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 7").Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .UserPicture "C:\Users\z188018\Desktop\Untitled.png"
        .TextureTile = msoFalse
        .RotateWithObject = msoTrue
    End With
```

And I can't adapt it.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm probably not much help actually writing this, but have you tried simply recording a macro of you performing the process and then modifying it to meet what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi hobenkr, I've edited my question to reflect your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm excel seems to think it's much simpler than I expected. Have you tried undoing the change and then running that macro to make the change back? That way you could at least verify that the macro indeed does what it's intended to. If so, that could suggest that maybe what you're trying to do matches quite a lot of default values.

Comment: Unfortunately, those aren't default values. I have 1 instance of the "block of code" for every mouse click.

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense. You may be right in that what was produced wasn't very useful, but this is a bit beyond my vba skills to do from scratch. If you want to post the full macro somewhere I'd be happy to try and stumble through it with you to see if we can't pull out the useful bits.

Answer (score 0):

This looks buggy and you have my sympathy.  You are not the first to encounter this.  In this post dating back to 2012 there is the same issue, code given will do some offsetting but will not come out of tile mode.

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/640887-visual-basic-applications-change-chart-porperties.html#post_3180924

All I can suggest from here is that you manipulate your image to fake it being resized and centred.   So do some image manipulation to (1) resize the image (2) enlarge the image giving white space in the new space then (3) offset the original portion of the image.  Sadly I do not know how to do this in code.

Quick Google and `Gimp`, a command line program might be useful.  https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

`Gimp` even has a stackoverflow tag so there is a community one can ask here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gimp